# Why is my cshtml page's javascript not updating/refreshing in the browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am moving an ASP.NET MVC3 application to MVC4 and it has been going well, I have most of it working and building properly. However, I need to tweak a little bit of one of the pages javascript and yet when I load it up in the browser it still displays the old script.

My initial thought was the cache, but I have refreshed the cache, hard refreshed the page (ctrl + f5 and ctrl + shift + r) and even turned the browser.cache.check_doc_frequency = 1 in firefox yet it is still loading up the previous script.

My second thought was that it was somehow picking up the view from the old MVC3 (following the guidelines I duplicated the project then edited it to migrate to MVC4) so edited that file as well. While this does change the javascript if I debug through the MVC3 version, the MVC4 version doesn't change.

Obviously I have spent a bit of time on google but everything I could find it turns out it was a caching problem, having seemingly ruled this out I have completely out of ideas.

Has anyone got any ideas of how to progress from here? Any other things I could try or where it could be picking up the old script from?

Comment: have you tried making a layout change?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the Visual Studio's development server to debug/develop your code? It may be caching static files. I'd suggest you try stopping the server (locate the dev server icon in your task bar, right click, exit) then run your app again.

Comment: I am using VS and think I have found the problem. There were some excluded files from the folder structure hidden from the solution explorer as I had 'Show all files' turned off. I was under the impression it wouldn't pick these up but it clearly has been. Removing these and now it is picking up the correct file. 

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Append a date string as a query parameter when you fetch the javascript..This way the js will never be chached